# Why [UIBarButtonItem setCustomView:] method disable segue in Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

I have Storyboard in my project. I use `[UIBarButtonItem setCustomView:]` method to customize toolbar buttons. For example:

```
[self setCustomView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image]];
```

Now they looks as I need. But I found that this method somehow disables segue that I set for this toolbar item. I mean, segue works without it, but when I tried to use this method for customization segue don't work. But why?

I don't want to use target-action pattern from code, I believe it is possible to use only Storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried what you have done with the same result - the picture is correct but the UIBarButtonItem doesn't react when pressed. Possibly this is a bug. My work around is as follows:

To do this in storyboard add a UIButton to the tool bar. You should see that storyboard adds it by putting the UIButton inside of the UIBarButton. Add the segue on the UIButton. Customize the UIButton in storyboard. In my App I set the size to 40 x 40. Then in your code customize the UIButton with the view. Here is an example of the code to add the imageView to the UIButton:

```
[sampleImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
[swapButton addSubview:sampleImageView];
```

Note: Storyboard can be quirky about adding UIButtons to toolbars. It seems as if you do it in a toolbar that is tied to a navigation controller it won't let you add it. I've worked around this by adding a dummy view controller to the storyboard, adding a toolbar to that, then dragging the UIButton into that toolbar. Storyboard will create that for you by encapsulating the UIButton in a UIButtonBarItem. You can then copy then over to the the desired toolbar in your project and delete dummy view controller.

There are other ways to do this such as creating the buttons in code and adding them to the toolbar. The method above minimizes code.

Comment: hmmm... UIBarButton? may be UIBarButtonItem. But it has customView property. And I cant put UIButton into UIBarButtonItem in Storyboard. Can you explain what you mean more detailed.

Comment: @Lloyd18 I standed corrected on the UIBArButtonItem. I've updated my answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to configure all of the segues in the storyboard as well but I needed to create a custom view for the rightBarButtonItem. To make sure the segue still works, just add this line before setting the customView:

```
[filterButton addTarget:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target action:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

This way the segues you set up in your storyboard will still fire with customViews.

My entire custom button code looks like this:

```
UIButton *filterButton =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[filterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"filter"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[filterButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 36)];
[filterButton addTarget:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.target action:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.customView = filterButton;
```